# Webgrid select row without using SelectLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using MVC4 & Razor.

In my cshtml file I have a Webgrid. How can I select a row without using selectLink or checkbox or Radio button?

The scenario that I'm trying to achieve here is -

In Webgrid to display column with data and then select one single row WITHOUT USING selectLink or something like that. And based on this selection, send this value to Controller.

As to what I've tried so far...
I've been following the tutorial from these links below -
[Example 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/02/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid-part-2.aspx)
[Example 2](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/154/Looking-At-The-WebMatrix-WebGrid)

Both the examples are good but they both use SelectLink approach. Can someone give an example?

Comment: How do you want the row to be selected then?  By just clicking on the row itself, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the WebGrid's own functionality you could just use some jQuery to trigger a row select when they click anywhere in the row like so:

```
$(function () {

    // this selector should target the WebGrid table, with an id or class that is
    // set on the table
    $('table > body > tr').click(function () {

        // this will depend on how you action and routes are set up but this will
        // work for the default route of "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
        // also this will simply redirect to the URL with the selected row value,
        // if your intention is to stay on the page consider using jQuery's ajax
        // methods (i.e. .load(), $.get(), $.post() or $.ajax())
        $(location).attr('href', @Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController") + '/' + /* get row value */)

    });

});
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the reply. I'm kinda new to JQuery.

Can you please explain what this part means and does?

$('table > body > tr')

I understand that the click function will be called once
the user clicks inside the row. I didn't understand this
('table > body > tr')... 

Thanks once again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: That piece is called a jQuery selector http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  They basically follow the rules of CSS selectors.  The syntax `$(table > tbody > tr)` creates a jQuery object from the elements selected, in this case all `tr` elements that are a child of a `body` element which are in turn a child of a `table` element.